# Stochastic Dominance between Binomials w/ Different Parameters

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What is the minimum boost, $y$, we need such that $Bin(x+y,\frac{p}{n}) \succeq Bin(x,p)$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I am not entirely sure how to proceed to answer this. From a coupling perspective, we may let $X_1 = Bin(x,p)$ and take $\frac{1}{n}$ of these to get $X_2 = Bin(x,\frac{p}{n})$. Then, we want to make up the difference $X_2 - X_1$ by adding a "binomial-distributed boost" to $X_2$, but such a boost always has some probability of being less than $X_1$. However, if the boost somehow depends on $X_1$, then I feel like we can't answer the question this way.

Any ideas?